# How to go the link when click button vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This is my button. when I click the button it wont go to particular link. but the link changed in browser's url field.

<button v-for="student_record in student.student_records" class="dropdown-item custom-dropdown" @click="$router.push('/student/'+student.uuid+'/fee/'+student_record.id)"> {{student_record.batch.course.name}} {{trans('finance.fee_allocation')}}

I need to go the link when button clicked. or another solution is add multiple function on @click. first function is same. and reload the page is second function. ie @click load function and then load second function after first function.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of JeRmiZa answer, I'd like to add an alternative option that is more readable in the template and requires no programmic routing.

Use vue-router's router-link component:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#router-link

```html
<router-link v-for="s in student.student_records" :to="`/student/${s.uuid}/fee/${student_record.id}`">
  <button class="dropdown-item custom-dropdown"> 
    {{student_record.batch.course.name}} {{trans('finance.fee_allocation')}}
  </button>
</router-link>
```